# DDay ical - Saving event data to database with Nhibernate

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate, dday

My application needs calendar information and I would like to use a format/schema that is compatible with .ical so it can integrate with other calendar systems.

[DDay iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/pages/projects/dday.ical/) seems to be the only .Net library available that does this.

However I don't see any way to save the objects to a database. I'm using Nhibernate, so I'd like a natural way to do this.

Has anyone already done this? Am I missing something in the DDay iCal library? Any suggestions?

Is my only option modifying the source code?

Comment: Try to serialize it, and convert it to a byte array. Then just try to persist it.

Comment: serialization is one way, or you might try writing the mappings yourself as suggested by the author of dday.ical (see http://sourceforge.net/p/dday-ical/discussion/656447/thread/dfc47faa/ )

Answer (score 1):

([Don't use dday.ical](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/wiki); use [ical.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net). It contains many performance enhancements and bugfixes.)

I don't know anything about NHibernate, but icalendar is a serialization format. You can just emit ical-serialized text representing your calendar(s) and their event(s).

Here's a working example from the [ical.net](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/wiki) wiki:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var later = now.AddHours(1);

//Repeat daily for 5 days
var rrule = new RecurrencePattern(FrequencyType.Daily, 1) { Count = 5 };

var e = new Event
{
    DtStart = new CalDateTime(now),
    DtEnd = new CalDateTime(later),
    RecurrenceRules = new List<IRecurrencePattern> { rrule },
};

var calendar = new Calendar();
calendar.Events.Add(e);

var serializer = new CalendarSerializer(new SerializationContext());
var serializedCalendar = serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
```

This will emit ical-serialized text that can be stored in a database using any framework you wish. The serialized text will look something like this:

```
BEGIN: VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID: -//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 2.1//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20160704T172520
DTSTAMP:20160704T162520
DTSTART:20160704T162520
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5
SEQUENCE: 0
UID: f4693a88-0a57-4761-b949-8822b8a507d2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```